# vb.net loop through and assign values if statement is true

Tags: vb.net, printing, break

i am working in vb.net and trying to organise what i'm calling a meal/entree break .
 the code i have looks right to me but it just isn't working.
it is supposed to find entree's then mains then all else and print in that order but
it prints the results in order of clicked instead of in the order i've defined. 
to keep in mind, i am using a reference to a vb6 code "powerpack" to use old school print codes that i'm more comfortable.
i have assigned some public shared variables:

```
Public Shared item(25) As String
Public Shared bar(25) As String
Public Shared price(25) As Integer
Public Shared barprice(25) As Integer
Public Shared EntreeBreak(25) As Boolean
Public Shared MainBreak(25) As Boolean
Public Shared Print_Items(25) As String
Public Shared Print_price(25) As Integer
```

i then have created a global class that i call public shared subs from, the sub i am calling is

```
Dim i2 As Integer
        i = 1
        i2 = 1

        Do Until i = 26
            If item(i) <> "" Then
                If EntreeBreak(i) = True And i2 < 26 Then
                    Print_Items(i2) = item(i)
                    Print_price(i2) = price(i)
                    i2 = i2 + 1
                ElseIf MainBreak(i) = True And i2 < 26 Then
                    Print_Items(i2) = item(i)
                    Print_price(i2) = price(i)
                    i2 = i2 + 1
                ElseIf EntreeBreak(i) = False And MainBreak(i) = False And i2 < 26 Then
                    Print_Items(i2) = item(i)
                    Print_price(i2) = price(i)
                    i2 = i2 + 1
                End If
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop
```

i just can't find what i'm doing wrong
it is supposed to find entree's then mains then all else but
it prints the results in order of clicked instead of in the order i've defined.

Comment: Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: Actually you are just copying the items from item and price to Print_items and print_price, just leaving out the empty items. Your if/elseif look kinda unnecessary. And don't forget that arrays start at index 0 not 1

Answer (score 0):

You are just looping through item in order from 1 to 26
I am assuming item has a mix of entrees, mains and all else, so perhaps what you need to do is loop through the item three times, firstly extracting the entrees, then the mains, then all else.
Having said that i would encourage you to use a better data structure, possible an ordered dictionary and meal class/structure or something.  and as said above you should be looping from 0 to 25, or if it is a dictionary or a list , just a for each will do.